# 3D screw type sites for different bits

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

Does anyone know if there is a site that has 3D images of different type of screw bits. I just ran into a bit supposedly it's called a triangle wedge special screw.

I'm sick of buying all these different tools and plan on making an adapter bit and 3D printing it out on a 3D printer. Example: I would have the triangle wedge special screw male section on one end and have a Phillips/cross on the other, that way I would just need a Phillips head screw driver to unscrew this thing.  If I run into other special heads I could just print out a new bit using the same process. Since it's such a small item the 3d printout won't take that long. Does anyone know if such a site with thousand of different 3D screw heads exists?  Here's an 3D animation/video of the bit adapter **on top** which would be printed out in 3D.

Here's a video
[vid of my goal with new bit](http://youtu.be/1bcBLzVtmJA)

[image: triangle wedge special screw]

Comment: Not really programming related, so off-topic. Also, I don't think 3d printing material is well-suited for this task.

Comment: @PeterT I thought stackoverflow was for the overflow.  The 3D Stack-exchange was discontinued.  Any other ideas where it should go?

Comment: nope, what is on-topic can be read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic